# how can I make random number with html?

Tags: html

I want to make random numbers with html
Is there any way for this?
the function of java script for this is .random(); but I want just use html

Answer (score 4):

You can't, you have to use JavaScript `Math.random()`.

Comment: are you sure? I heard html has this posibility

Comment: @arezoo You heard wrong, HTML was never intended to do any forms of computations.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is just a way of describing the **content** and **layout** of a page.  In order to add **dynamic** content or **interactivity**, it is necessary to use JavaScript.

In this instance:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("random-number").innerHTML = Math.random(); 
};
```

```html
<div id="random-number"></div>
```